# Unable to read file with python

Tags: python, file

I'm trying to read the content of a file with python 3.8.5 but the output is empty, I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Here is the code:

```py
import subprocess
import os

filename = "ls.out"
ls_command = "ls -la"
file = open(filename, "w")
subprocess.Popen(ls_command, stdout=file, shell=True)
file.close()

# So far, all is ok. The file "ls.out" is correctly created and filled with the output of "ls -la" command"

file = open(filename, "r")
for line in file:
    print(line)
file.close()
```

The output of this script is empty, it doesn't print anything. I'm not able to see the content of `ls.out`.

What is not correct here ?

Comment: Just curious - any reason not to use python to read directory content?

Comment: Yes, "ls -la" was just an example. The exact command is more complex. I just didn't want to pollute the post with it.

Comment: I tried communicating with the Popen and the output was also blank, so there might be some problem with how you ran the command.

Comment: I just tried adding `p.terminate()` before closing the file and still blank output

Comment: Does it work using the `with open(blarg) as file` context syntax?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Popen creates a new process and launches it but returns immediately.  So the end result is that you've `fork`ed your code and have both processes running at once.  Your python code in executing faster than the start and finish of `ls`.  Thus, you need to wait for the process to finish by adding a call to `wait()`:

```
import subprocess
import os

filename = "ls.out"
ls_command = "ls -la"
file = open(filename, "w")
proc = subprocess.Popen(ls_command, stdout=file, shell=True)
proc.wait()
file.close()


file = open(filename, "r")
for line in file:
    print(line)
file.close()
```

Comment: Thanks! This is what I was missing. Now it's working fine

Answer (score 1):

`Popen` merely *starts* the subprocess. Chances are the file is not yet populated when you `open` it.

If you want to wait for the `Popen` object to finish, you have to call its `wait` method, etc; but a much better and simpler solution is to use `subprocess.check_call()` or one of the other higher-level wrappers.

If the command prints to standard output, why don't you read it drectly?

```py
import subprocess
import shlex

result = subprocess.run(
    shlex.split(ls_command), # avoid shell=True
    check=True, text=True, capture_output=True)
line = result.stdout
```

Comment: For (much) more on this topic, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4256107/running-bash-commands-in-python/51950538#51950538